# Is time complexity calculated based on how many time program has to work on single input

Tags: javascript, time-complexity

I wanted to ask this question about Big O Notation. To my understanding `n` is the number of inputs.
I got in a debate with several of my colleagues about this issue.
Suppose we have an array of arrays.
Array containing all the array has the length N. and each array in that array has the length M. So we have a matrix of N x M.

Suppose the question is calculate the sum of all array. so I will write a program like this.

```
let sum = 0;
for (let a = 0; a < containerArray.length; a++) {
  let innerArray = containerArray[a];
  for (let b = 0; b < innerArray.length; b++) {
    sum += innerArray[b];
  }
}
```

The debate is, I think this program has the time complexity of O( n ) . Why ? Because our program is not executed more than the number of inputs. Even if the number of inputs is N x M program never exceeds the number of iterations that of number of inputs.
While my colleagues think since you have the nested loop, time complexity is O(n^2).
Please guide me.

Comment: Neither of you are correct. You've defined two variables `N` and `M`, then decided to calculate time complexity in terms of `n` which you haven't defined. The time complexity is O( N x M ).

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Which then again is N since no matter how much the input is it is considered `N`. `N x M` is just a theoratical  variable which should be considered N.

Comment: Assuming big O notation describes how the number of iterations relates to the size of the input in worst case scenario, if `a` and `b` are not related (`a` may grow, while `b` stays the same). Above code implements O(n)-time algorithm since from `a` standpoint there's no nested loop. If `b` is linearly dependent from `a`, that would be O(n²)-time complexity.

Comment: according to sample `a = b`  so its O(n^2)

Comment: @Aman : not true - maximum value of `a` is the length of `containerArray`, while maximum `b` correspond to the length of the nested arrays `containerArray[i]`

Comment: from math perspective that is more than O(n^2) cause you also take time to sum each time we inside second array

Comment: From what I understand. time complexity is calculated based on how many time iterations are performed against a single input. In this case, number of iterations is not greater than the number of inputs regardless of the size of the array.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov if we looking from inside javascript, time complexity could be less if this arrays store only address of the value in cache

Comment: @Arman suppose we have a program where we have to calculate factorial for each element in the array of length `N` . In this case, for each element there will be multiple iterations. hence number of iterations are greater than the number of inputs.
But in above case. number of iterations will always be equal to the number of inputs.

Comment: N x M = J = O ( J ) simple math ?

Comment: @MamoonAhmed Here i see following pattern: first we enter inside `containerArray` array and find element `a` then we get inside `innerArray` and find element `b` then we sum with value `sum` the b-th element, i doubt that js knows where a-th and b-th elements located by default so it manually searches for that index through the arrays. Please correct me if I missed something or incorrect.

Comment: n is not the number of inputs. n is the number of iterations or repetitions programs has to go against inputs. This is my understanding though.

Comment: @Arman suppose this program is written in C which know where each element in the array is located. Then time complexity is O (n ) ?
because since `a` is an input `b` is also an input. so even if its a matrix or even if there is a nested loop. both inner and container arrays are inputs given bu the user. program is not executing more than 1 time for each input.

Comment: Well if C knows where a-th and b-th elements are in the array that is amazing it could be O(n) no matter what :) I was wrong it is not O(n^2) check [that](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00sc-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-spring-2011/unit-1/lecture-8-efficiency-and-order-of-growth/MIT6_00SCS11_rec04.pdf) course. It is less but not O(n) because on second iteration `innerArray` has 2 elements then 3 etc.

Comment: @Arman I am sorry I didnt get your point about `It is less but not O(n) because on second itereration innerArray has 2 elements then 3 etc`

Comment: Well after first loop we have 1 element in `innerArray`, then 2 ... then `containerArray.length` so each time it becomes bigger we spent more time searching b-th element inside it to sum so i guess it is around (n log n)

Comment: @Arman In case of arrays, program doesnt have to search for the location of the array. index based arrays does not have to perform a search. if we are talking about hash map or JSON objects on Javascript we can say that it needs to calculate the index but in that case too, notation would be O ( n ) because calculating the hash is part of the execution even if the number of inputs are reduced.

Comment: If you provided some documentations or references on your answer how js works under hood would be great. 
Also i can not understand why 2 people think first comment useful? It is wrong in many ways! first array exist but second is empty and initialized inside first loop and fill up after so it can't be N*M. It could be N*M if M was full in first place like N one

Comment: @Arman because its a first comment and no one bothers to read the rest of the discussion.